# Spotfire Case statement find text

Tags: case, spotfire

I must be drawing a blank but I need to write a case statement that searches the text and if "(2)" exists anywhere within the text then "two" else if "(3)" exists anywhere in the text then "three". The text values are varying lengths and appear in different parts of the string so I can't use a right() or left(). I tried using the 'case when [column] ~= "(2)" then "two" ......end' but it didn't work properly.

Comment: You are close you just need a preceding and trailing wild card of 0 or more characters with *. Right now it's REGEX explicitly looking for only that with nothing else possible on either side... so essentially the same as using =  you can also use RxReplace. If no one has answered by tomorrow I'll give you one when I'm back at my box but hopefully this helps. At a minimum it'll set someone up to answer you.

Comment: Chris did this work out for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an expression that should get you what you want:

```
case  
    when [Value]~=".*\\(2\\).*" then "Two" 
    when [Value]~=".*\\(3\\).*" then "Three"
end
```

Note that `CASE` statements are executed in order, and `BREAK` once a condition is met. Thus, as you see in the 4th row, if both (2) and (3) are present, it will result to true for "Two" and the "Three" check will never happen.

[image: Results]

Comment: Sort of...when I use the * wild card it isn't working. Is it because I'm typing "*(2)*" and it interprets the * as part of the string?

Comment: @Chris  Are you are trying to use a property control?

Comment: No, just trying to figure out how to use a wildcard in a string in a Case statment expression because whenever I use the * within quotations it interprets it as part of the actual string and not as a wild card operator.

Comment: @Chris It depends if you want ONE character or unlimited. In what i posted above it's 0 or more characters, using the .* If you want just ONE character that is usually just . or _ but can you elaborate on why the above code didn't work for you if you copy it exactly?